# How can I highlight each bullet point in Powerpoint with the full text appearing at once?

Tags: powerpoint

I'm trying to animate a PowerPoint slide, where I'd like the full five dot points to be present on the screen at all times, but on click, each bullet point would individually highlight.
I can get it so they appear on click and then dim after a click, but I'd like all the points to be on the screen at the start, rather than getting revealed one-by-one.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Answer (score 0):

@JohnKorchok is correct - this is not programming. Use as Animation EMPHASIS -> OBJECT COLOR. Effect Options: PER PARAGRAPH. Than double click on each Animation and choose a highlight color AND the original color in the field AFTER ANIMATION.